# How to return images from specific hashtag on Instagram iOS

Tags: ios, instagram, hashtag

In my iPhone app I want to return all images from a specific hashtag on Instagram. Does anyone know a good tutorial which covers this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/)?

You can get media from "tags" using the following endpoint:

`GET /tags/<tag-name>/media/recent`

Read more here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search